# Amazon RDS Proxy Closing Connections

Tags: mysql, node-mysql, amazon-rds-proxy

I'm using Amazon RDS Proxy for my main database for my node application. I recently noticed that in my server logs I was receiving a lot of fatal PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST errors with my database instance which would cause my server to reboot (using PM2). This would of course cause a few seconds of downtime each time it reboots causing intermittent client errors. I use node-mysql to manage my database connections and I use connection pooling for my server mysql instances. Looking into my Amazon RDS Proxy logs I see a lot of instances of both:

1. The client connection closed. Reason: The idle timeout was exceeded.
2. The client connection closed. Reason: The TCP channel was closed by either the client or the proxy.

What exactly is causing this to happen and what can I do to stop this behaviour?

Thanks!